# How to say a "Murder mystery dinner" in Portuguese?

Tags: tradução-inglês

I have hosted several murder mystery dinner parties and games, described by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_dinner) as:

> A mystery dinner is a popular type of dinner theater in which the play is a murder mystery, and the diners are invited to solve the mystery as they eat and watch the play. ... There are also kits available for "hosting your own murder mystery dinner" at home, as well as troupes of actors who perform (and cater) private shows, or mystery dinners, in client's homes. Some such kits may not be specifically written for a dinner event, but can be adapted to suit that purpose.

I have played them in English and would now like to play one in Portuguese. I cannot find results with the translation "jantar mistério".

Does such a concept exist in Portuguese-speaking countries? If so, what is the name?

Comment: The term is dinner theater, if you go to a place. You have to invent it in Portuguese. Teatro de mistério com jantar, por exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game is most likely usually also called "Murder Mystery" or "Murder Party" in Portuguese, like it is in [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_party) and [Italian](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_party_(gioco)) and in this [Lisbon webpage](https://lisboasecreta.co/jogo-imersivo-murder-mystery-datas-e-bilhetes/).

One could say "jogo de mistério" ("mystery game"), but this is rather a class of games. Another possibility could be "[Jogo de] Mistério de Assassinato", but it doesn't really seem to be used.

I suspect that's due to such games not being popular enough in Portuguese-speaking countries.

Another puzzle game, [Escape room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_room), is often called by its name in English, even though it does have a Portuguese version of the name, "Jogo de Fuga". Also the game "Clue" (mostly "Cluedo" outside the US) most often keeps its foreign name in Portuguese, even though it could easily be translated (e.g., as "Pista" or "Indício").

## Update from OP

I have since by chance found another example of a "murder mystery":

> MURDER MYSTERY
>
> O QUE É?
>
> Uma refeição verdadeiramente inquietante é a descrição ideal para o
>   “Murder Mystery”, um programa totalmente inovador num detalhe
>   determinante: são os clientes que dão vida aos personagens e resolvem
>   o crime!
>
> ...
>
> O INTERROGATÓRIO
>
> Durante as interações e os interrogatórios os participantes estarão a
>   ser avaliados pelo staff presente, tendo em conta o cumprimento dos
>   objetivos atribuídos a cada um inicialmente (3 objetivos secundários e
>   1 objetivo principal).
>
> As missões são simples e implicam a interação com os outros
>   participantes. A título de exemplo: “coloque este papel no bolso do
>   personagem X e exponha-o publicamente quando estiver a ser
>   interrogado” ou “deixe uma marca de batom na camisa do Padrinho”.

The source is [here](https://odesassossego.com/cardapio/murder-mystery) but note that this is not a recommendation, I have not tried them, and have no affiliation.

Comment: I was going to say :"Jogo do mistério do crime" as the most appropriate translation, roughly:"Crime mistery game".

Comment: @bad_coder Also possible, though very clumsy.

Comment: Side note: in Portugal, I've always known Cluedo as Cluedo; I've never heard "Clue".

Comment: @ANeves Good point, I meant mostly how I found it now in Brazilian online shops. I took a better look at it and now the comment on Cluedo/Clue is amended.

Comment: This seems reasonable. As you say, I probably cannot find any scripts or game kits because they are less popular in Portugal and Brazil.

Comment: The point is you go out to dinner and the organizers present a mystery as a play to you to solve. What's the point of leaving it in English?

Comment: @Lambie Indeed I'm sure most will play it in Portuguese, my answer is just about the name of the game.

Comment: But dinner theater is a common thing in the states. Hosting one at home is not called dinner theater. As they say "Hosting a murder mystery dinner" is not the same thing.

Comment: @Lambie True, simply playing the game with a kit has little to do with having actors coming to your place perform for your guests. Never heard about the latter in Brazil (which one might call a "peça policial" ou "peça de mistério"), that's why I don't even mention the play in my answer. I might add it later on.